# Finding multiple values in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a word highlighting jquery plugin that can detect one word in a div (pre in this case), and highlight it. I edited it so it can detect more than one word, but it can only detect one word per function, I want it to find multiple words per function (Sort of like a syntax highlighter).
**HTML:**

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="i.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="css.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="page();">
<button ontouchstart="page()">execute</button>
<script>
function page() {
get();
spud();
spuds();
getting();
}

function getting() {
var rego = 'get';
$('pre').highlight(rego,'green');
}

function get() {
var regi = 'hget';
    $('pre').highlight(regi,'green');
}

function spud() {
var you = 'potato';
$('pre').highlight(you,'highlight'); // change 'you' with a var value
}

function spuds() {
var your = 'chips';
   $('pre').highlight(you,'highlight'); // change 'you' with a var value
    }

</script>

<pre contenteditable="true" id="pre">
get potato chips
hget potato chips now
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.highlight { color: red }
.green { color:green}
```

**Plugin:**

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(e,spill) {
function t(e, i) {
    var h = 0;
    if (3 == e.nodeType) {
        var n = e.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(i);
        if (n -= e.data.substr(0, n).toUpperCase().length - e.data.substr(0, n).length, 
        n >= 0) {
            var a = document.createElement("pig");
            a.className = spill;
            var r = e.splitText(n);
            r.splitText(i.length);
            var s = r.cloneNode(!0);
            a.appendChild(s), r.parentNode.replaceChild(a, r), h = 1;
        }
    } else if (1 == e.nodeType && e.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(e.tagName)) for (var l = 0; l < e.childNodes.length; ++l) l += t(e.childNodes[l], i);
    return h;
}
return this.length && e && e.length ? this.each(function() {
    t(this, e.toUpperCase());
}) :this;
}, jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
 return this.find("pig."+spill+"").each(function() {
        with (this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName, this.parentNode)    replaceChild(this.firstChild, this), 
      normalize();
 }).end();
};
```

My aim is to have multiple values in the vars `rego regi you your`
. For example, in var `your` I want something like: `var your = "chips","kumara","grease";` 
, and I have tried `var your = ["chips","kumara","grease"];`, but it dosen't work.

Comment: what are you saying...you wrote this plugin and want direction to add that functionality?

Comment: No, I downloaded the plugin, and I want it to detect more than one word

Comment: Is there another way other than forEach? I am not quite sure how to put it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try replacing:

```
return this.length && e && e.length ? this.each(function() {
    t(this, e.toUpperCase());
}) :this;
```

With

```
return this.length && e && e.length ? this.each(function() {
    var arr = typeof e === 'string' ? [e] : e,
        self=this; 
    $.each(arr, function(_, term){
        if(term.length){
           t(self, term.toUpperCase());
        }
    });    
}) :this;
```

It is checking now if the value is a string or array so you can use either